# Java Servlet 404 issues

Tags: java, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am working on a simple program redirection by making some calls to a servlet. However, for some reason, I am continuously getting a 404 error every time I try to construct the code in this particular project build.

It may be of note that I am building this project in Eclipse and am using Apache Tomcat.

here is my coding....

HTML first:

To save some aggrivation, this is the particular snippet on where the problems arise. My connection to the MySQL database along with the database reads are operating perfectly fine.

```
<form action="objectServer" method="get">
    <select name="choice">
        <% while (rs.next()){ %>
        <option value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>"><%=rs.getString(2) %></option>
        <% }
            MysqlConnection.close(connect);
        %>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="View the Descrition!" />
</form>
```

Java code:

The first is a simple java class that validates whether an item has been selected and acts to help redirect.

```
package com.program.service;

public class Service {
    public boolean redirect(String selected){
        if( (selected == null) || (selected == "") ){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the servlet itself.

```
package com.program.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.wines.service.Service;


@WebServlet("/objectServer")
public class InfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String selected = request.getParameter("choice");
        Service service = new Service();
        boolean redirector = service.redirect(selected);
        if(redirector){
            response.sendRedirect("next_page.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("this_page.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

As one can see, this is a REALLY simple program that should be redirecting to the next page, but for some reason I am missing something that I just cannot see at this moment. I don't don't know whether it's an issue with my coding, my server, or something else I could have missed. As a note, the web.xml has not been programmed in this particular application as of yet.

Comment: Without web.xml, how are you able to deploy it in tomcat? web.xml will tel the container what need to be done..

Comment: What's the Url you are hitting to get the error page? If so where have you mapped the Url with the servlet?

Comment: Looks like your servlet and one of yours page are not in the same path location. It would be great if you post an example of your project folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, your jsp's are most likely can be only accessed through Servlets. In this case, you will need to use "forward" instead of "redirect". Please understand the differences between "forward" and "redirect". Here is a good read: [Forward versus redirect](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181)

Example Forward:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = aRequest.getRequestDispatcher("this_page.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(aRequest, aResponse);
```

Example redirect:

```
response.sendRedirect(absoluteOrRelativeURL); // e.g absoluteOrRelativeURL= "objectServer"
```

Comment: *You cannot redirect to .jsp since the jsp's are not directly accessed.* you're wrong, this can be done if the JSPs are in the main folder of web app instead of being inside WEB-INF, it will invoke a GET request on the `next_page.jsp` URL. Replacing redirect per forwarding *could* solve the problem. By the way, when you say *if you intend to redirect, then you must redirect to a Servlet and not jsp* you probably meant to do this in order to pre process the page by the servlet in the `doGet` method. Please expand your answer about these topics.

Answer (score 0):

if your JSP pages are  resides under the WEB-INF, you cannot redirect to the JSP page. this is because the content under the WEB-INFare  restricted  from the direct access. therefore  you have to forward the request for that resource. that can be  done by modifying you method as  follows. ( i have  assumed that your jsp pages are  resides directly under the WEB-INF directory)

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String selected = request.getParameter("choice");
        Service service = new Service();
        boolean redirector = service.redirect(selected);
        if(redirector){
          request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/next_page.jsp").forward(request,response);
        } else {
          request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/this_page.jsp").forward(request,response);
        }
    }
```

further more, if you wish to make a ridirect for particular resource, make sure to do the redirect for a servlet mapping. you cannot make a redirect for a particular resource  resides  under the WEB-INF directory.